# How to use free space for partition

Tags: partition, fdisk

```
[root@shine home]# fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3c889e03
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1        2089    16777216   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2            2089        2155      524288   83  Linux
/dev/sda3            2155       15209   104857600   83  Linux
/dev/sda4           15209      282558  2147483647+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5           15209      282428  2146435072   83  Linux
```

I have 4TB hard drive from which I have only used 2TB. How can I create more partition and use full space?

I am not sure what the /dev/sda4 partition is. Can I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer already provided answers your original question, I feel you are looking for another question.

> How can I use all 4 TB of storage on my drive?

You need to switch from MBR to GPT. gdisk can do the job.
In your particular case, you will need to remove the swap partition temporarily. It is in the way of the main GPT. You can re-add the swap partition after the conversion to GPT is completed.
You can then use gparted to either add another partition or to extend sda5.
All of these steps should not affect your data, but please have a backup in case something goes wrong.

Chances are, you will also need to re-install your boot-loader. You can switch to EFI style booting or stay with legacy BIOS boot. You need a boot partition in either case. See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/961312/how-to-create-hybrid-live-usb/1047690#1047690) for the commands (you do not need the removable flag, though).

Answer (score -1):

You can only have four partitions in an MBR - unless one (or more? never tried that) of them are "extended partitions" (like your sda4) which are containers that can contain four more. I.e. sda4 is just a directory entry pointing to a new space to hold up to 4 partitions, but you only have one (sda5) in there ...

Comment: Thank you. So can  I remove sda4 and create new extended partition ?

Comment: Assuming you don't mind losing sda5 in the process...

Answer (score -1):

It almost looks like you have an extended partition already. And if you do, you should be able to divide that extended partition up into more partitions (Which they call Logical Partitions) and set up Linux in the Logical Partitions, that's how I installed it.

I had this problem on my laptop, I had all 4 partitions taken up and all of them were being used for something. With a little research though, I found a solution. If you need to make more partitions, you can use an extended partition to hold your other partition. Here's an example (My Computer)

1. 220GB NTFS Volume for Windows
2. 15GB NTFS Recovery Partition
3. 4GB FAT32 Partition for HP Diagnostic Tools
4. 199MB SYSTEM Partition

To fix the problem, I got rid of a partition (This was the SYSTEM partition in my case), made changes to my Windows partition to make up for the lost boot partition, booted from the Linux USB (for me it was Kali Linux), and started the installation process.

While installing, it will ask for a partitioning scheme. This is where you select to manually partition it. You should see the unallocated space you made from the deleted partition before (In my case, I had to shrink one of my volumes to make more unallocated space). While selecting to format the unallocated space, you should be able to make an extended partition. When you make it extended, you will see you have 4 partitions, but you can use the free space in the extended partition you made to make more partitions. For me, I had 1 partition left after deleting SYSTEM. I turned the unallocated space into an extended partition and put my swap, root, and home partitions in that extended partition. I now had 7 partitions and Kali Linux installed.